# Logging 403 Rewrites for Brute Force Attacks

Tags: mod-rewrite, wordpress, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks

As explained in Wordpress Codec, I want to prevent brute force attacks for wp-login.php via RewritetRule.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Deny_Access_to_No_Referrer_Requests

Rather than Codex's 301 Status Code, I want to Rewrite as 403 Forbidden status and make it log as "**client denied by server configuration**" so that Fail2Ban can process the log and block the IP.

I am using below code.

```
# Stop spam attack logins and comments
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(wp-comments-post|wp-login)\.php*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*example.com.* [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [R=403,L]
</ifModule>
```

It forbids the POST attacks as 403 status code, but I do not see any log about the incidence in error_log.

How can I make RewriteRule to log the incidence as normal 403 log in error_log? And is Rewrite + Fail2Ban configuration to deal with Brute Force attacks efficient about server management or not?

Comment: Have you actually received such an attempt since installing this configuration?

Comment: Yes I am trying AJAX POST examples with browser extensions. Is not it valid?

Answer (score 1):

You will not see these attempts in the error_log. You will see entries in the access_log for them so you would configure fail2ban to ban IPs that reached a 403 status code when accessing that specific URL, based on the access logs entries.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide any failregex and jail.local details for that please?